# Why isn't this working? Comparing elements in two 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays

For some reason this will always return 0? Why? I compare two 2d arrays of Space objects, which have a specific colour on them. I have made sure the two 2d arrays I am comparing are different but the method won't work?

```
public int compareArray(Space[][] test1, Space[][] test2)
{
    for(int row = 0;row< test1.length;row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column<test1.length;column++)
        {
            if(!((test1[row][column]).getColour()).equals(test2[row]    [column].getColour()))
            {
                System.out.println("Found a non match");
                return 1;
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I call this method here, the evenNumber method, changes test, and makes it different to test2, it's for the project I'm doing

```
public void testMethods()
   {
       Space[][] test = new Space[4][4];
   Space[][] test2= new Space[4][4];

   for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < test.length; j++){
              test[i][j] =  new Space(spaceColour.Null); 
              test2[i][j] =  new Space(spaceColour.Null);
         }
    }


   test[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.White); 
   test[1][1].setColour(spaceColour.White);  
   test[2][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 
   test[2][2].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 

   test2[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.White); 
   test2[1][1].setColour(spaceColour.White);  
   test2[2][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 
   test2[2][2].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 

  System.out.println(compareArray(test, test2));


   evenNumber(test);
   drawBoard(test);
   System.out.println("");
   drawBoard(test2);

 }
```

Comment: what if the length of test1 < length of test 2? are you considering that case?

Comment: Can we see what's calling this method? The issue might be there instead.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: Did you write the Color class and does it have an equals() method?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if this only returns `1` or `0`, why aren't we using `boolean`?

Comment: I used boolean, you can use it as well, I changed to int to see if it would make a difference

Comment: With the loops you have at the moment, you're getting the right result. You're only comparing items at the same row and column, so they will match in this case. Change test2[1][1]'s colour to Black and you should compareArray to return 0.

Comment: Thanks guys, silly mistake from me, I shouldn't work so late :)

Comment: I recommend printing both values just before the `if` statement (assuming you have a helpful `toString()` so you can see whether or not the values you're comparing should return true or false for your `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.White); 
test[1][1].setColour(spaceColour.White);  
test[2][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 
test[2][2].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 

test2[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.White); 
test2[1][1].setColour(spaceColour.White);  
test2[2][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 
test2[2][2].setColour(spaceColour.Black);
```

The colors of `test1` and `test2` are the same. So your if statements evaluates to `false` all the time, as you are checking if they are **not** the same.

Try with these values:

```
test[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.White); 
test[1][1].setColour(spaceColour.White);  
test[2][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 
test[2][2].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 

test2[0][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black); 
test2[1][1].setColour(spaceColour.Black);  
test2[2][1].setColour(spaceColour.White); 
test2[2][2].setColour(spaceColour.White);
```

Comment: No, "evenNumber method, changes test, and makes it different to test2"

Comment: Thanks, my bad, silly mistake, sorry to waste your time

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the second for loop from

```
for(int column = 0; column<test1.length;column++)
```

to

```
for(int column = 0; column<test1[0].length;column++)
```

Comment: that doesn't answer his question. The problem is his equals validates to true all the time

Comment: @EdgarBoda You are right. Without seeing the rest of the code I was guessing that his second dimension was longer and that is where the difference he was expecting to find lied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a little more

```
if (test1.length != test2.length) {
  return 1;
}
for(int row = 0;row< test1.length;row++)
{
  if (test1[row].length != test2[row].length) {
    return 1;
  }
  // back to your code
  for(int column = 0; column<test1[row].length;column++)
  {
    if(!((test1[row][column]).getColour()).equals(test2[row][column].getColour()))
    {
      System.out.println("Found a non match");
      return 1;
    }
  }
```